# Save past database record instead of being overwritten

Tags: java, database, sqlite

please help. We are building sort of a log in/ log out program, wherein we record the time he logs in and logs out, but we have a little problem, when he logs in again, the past record is overwritten. We just need some help of any ideas or methods of storing the past log in/ log out time instead of it being overwritten. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is creating a new record for each transaction too easy?

Comment: There is a lot of missing context.  What is the database structure, are you using a one-to-many relationship?  What are the connections between the user and the log?  How are you processing these requirements?

Answer (score 2):

you can use relational database for that like @MadProgrammer's statement.then you can keep a separate table for store user's login history .you don't need to overwrite.

for example see the picture below

i have show you a example er diagram and table structure for clarify

[image]

Comment: Yes! We definitely need this. Can this be done in sqlite? Thanks for helping!

Comment: @NicoDioso  Can this be done in sqlite? yes of couse .it should be possible with sqlite too.this kind of databases call relational databases .you can find lot of examples from internet .i just found this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/  tutorial which describes android -sqlite relational databse basic tutorial . it's not hard to learn .you have to learn little about sql join queries .so this tutorial will help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm but you will find more beginners tutorials. good luck....

Comment: This is very much appreciated sir madhawa

but we are using sqlite plugin on the firefox. not on android.

Comment: you can use join queries in your firefox application.

Answer (score 0):

Save this log as separate records.